# How to have Django *not* parse "{{variable}}" when using Jsrender?

Tags: javascript, python, django, jsrender

I am building a Django template which will use [jsrender](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsrender) in order to build out dynamic Javascript templates for html code.

However, I find that when I put a Jsrender template in my code, Django flips out because Django parses anything between `{{` and `}}` as a variable, and Jsrender uses this for its own variables. For instance, a template in Jsrender might look like:

```
    <script id="headerTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <h1>{{:label}}</h1>
    </script>
```

Django sees `{{:label}}` and tries to parse it, which leads to an error.

Is there a Django block I can invoke which would make Django *not* parse any text within it? Or otherwise to escape a `{` character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose alternative delimiters in JsRender, so as to avoid the conflict with Django delimiters.

https://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters

For example:

```
$.views.settings.delimiters("<%", "%>");
```

will change the tag syntax to `<%...%>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the [**`{% verbatim %} … {% endverbatim %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim):

```
{% verbatim %}
    <script id="headerTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <h1>{{:label}}</h1>
    </script>
{% endverbatim %}
```

This will thus render the double curly brackets, not interpret these.